# How to make a recycler view out of nodes which have nodes under them?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

[image: Firebase Realtime Database Schema]

So now I'd like to make a recycler view out of the UID nodes but I dont know how to implement the model class because a model class usually has a variable with a datatype and data assigned to it. Now in this case how do I make a model class, what datatype do I assign to the UID?

After I click on the UID, different cards should appear with the product name and after I click on the product the details should appear.

Thanks in Advance

Edit : I got the solution. Sorry , I wasn't able to frame the question properly.
I wanted to extract the UID nodes onto a model class so that I can display them as a list of cards in the recycler view and then navigate. I wasn't familiar with how recycler views worked so I couldn't figure out how I could extract the UIDs. I am posting my solution here. Please check the Log statement.
[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TO4Me.png)

Comment: This is quite a broad use-case. Can you show how far you got on your own already? For example: did you already try to read the database? Can you show the code of where you got stuck? Seeing what you tried drastically increases the chances that someone can help. Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far in code.

Answer (score 0):

[Solution to extract the UIDs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gu9YE.png)

After the extracting the UIDs onto a list, these can be then passed onto the adapter along with the model class to create a recycler view with every card containing the UID. To access the nodes under the UID, you can use Holder.OnClickListener and write another code block similar to this to extract the product details.

Instead of extracting the product details and following this method, you can try an alternative of using the FirebaseRecycler Adapter which automatically extracts the data for you.